# Split file with multimple delimiter and column numbers

Tags: r

I'm being provided with a statistical output file with the following structure:

```
> dput(x)
structure(list(V1 = c(0.236364, 0.032086, 0.062762, 0.095238, 
NaN, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0.258706, 0.436735, 0.104167, 0.611336, 0.160279
), V2 = c(0.183333, 0.623333, 0.796667, 0.14, 0, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 0.67, 0.816667, 0.96, 0.823333, 0.956667), V3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

a link to read data:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxSZDr4eTnb9aDhCOGRxVEV5aVE/edit?usp=sharing

**Data Properties:**

- No header
- The file uses a specific delimiter option
  numeric[space][tab][space]numeric[space][tab][space] # for 2 numeric column components
- Row numbers may obviously vary but will always the same for components 2 and 3

---

**I need to split it into data.frames of each component:**
1 component - 1st two column section
2 component - 1 column section
3 component - 2nd two column section

**I can't find a general way to split similar data files into there 3 components.**

I've found examples using different delimiters as split object but none with this particular case of column number and delimiter option.

Please let me know if the example is enough. I'm not sure how relevant the delimiter option may be for this particular problem. I think it is not.

Comment: it seems there are only two columns? Or is the last column followed by [space][tab][space]?
Can't you just use read.table, setting the delimiter to sep=" \t " (with spaces) and then take it from there?

Comment: @ako: yes there are only **two** columns with data but there are delimiters after every last numeric entry **in the 1st and 3rd sections**. They are irrelevant for extraction of data that matters. `read.table()` with properly handle reading data into 3 columns (3rd empty). This do not solve my problem which is finding a **general way** to split 3 components.

Comment: Will there ever be `NA` values in the second column of either component 1 or component 3?

Comment: could you show the output you expect as well, thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no `NA` values in the second column of either component 1 or component 3 data, `rle` could be of use here. The basic approach, if I understand your problem correctly and if the relevant conditions hold true, would be to look at the *runs* of `NA` values in the "V2" column in the `dput` data that you have shared. `is.na(x$V2)` would return a logical vector, and from that, we can use `rle` to determine where to split your data:

```
> RLE <- rle(is.na(x$V2))$lengths
> split(x, rep(seq(RLE), RLE))
$`1`
        V1       V2 V3
1 0.236364 0.183333 NA
2 0.032086 0.623333 NA
3 0.062762 0.796667 NA
4 0.095238 0.140000 NA
5      NaN 0.000000 NA

$`2`
   V1 V2 V3
6   0 NA NA
7   1 NA NA
8   2 NA NA
9   3 NA NA
10  4 NA NA

$`3`
         V1       V2 V3
11 0.258706 0.670000 NA
12 0.436735 0.816667 NA
13 0.104167 0.960000 NA
14 0.611336 0.823333 NA
15 0.160279 0.956667 NA
```

Comment: Mahti: Yes. Works as expected. V2 and V3 will always be NA for 2nd component and never for 1st and 3rd, which make it easy with your approach. This is the second useful example of rle I'm dicovering in a few days! Thanks. Now the idea is to `rbind()` non NA columns from list objects 2 and 3.

Comment: @PauloCardoso, Do you mean `rbind` objects 1 and 3? If that is your ultimate end goal, I would have taken a different approach: `> x$V3 <- NULL; > x[!is.na(x$V2), ]`

Comment: objects 2 and 3. using `x[!is.na(x$V2), ]` will not capture the desired components.

Comment: @PauloCardoso, then do you mean `cbind` and not `rbind`--not clear of your end goal still.

Comment: I mean `rbind()`. There is a correspondence between components 2 and 3. Each line of component 3 is a factor related to the same line of component 2. That is the reason components 2 and 3 will be the always the same. Is it clear? Thank you for discuss this.

Comment: How can you `rbind` (bind by rows) after removing NAs from 2 and 3? 2 will have just V1 and 3 will have V1 and V2. They dont have the same number of columns.

Comment: @Arun: Sorry, my mistake. I meant `cbind()`, naturally. There is no NAs at column 1 of components 2 and 3. I think it is solved. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

Could you start off by translating the 3 character delimiters into one character delims?

On the command line you could try:

```
cat input.txt | sed 's/ \t /\t/g' > input2.txt
```

This will replace all " \t "'s with "\t"'s

Or you could just open it up in your favorite txt editor and find/replace all

Once the delimiter is in a standard format it will be a lot easier to do the further processing

Comment: thank you. Delimiter seems to be easy to solve. A simple read.delim2() with no sep option will create 3 columns.